# .Net Framework: exception in w3wp.exe

Tags: asp.net, iis, w3wp.exe

I developed website with web forms in asp.net 3.5. I ran it with IIS. It worked good earlier. But exception occured suddenly, when I debugged it. Message was

> An unhandled Microsoft .Net Framework exception occured in w3wp.exe
>   [XXXX]

It occurs every time when I try to run my application, but when I run website with Cassini there is no exception. There is no exception, when I deploy html page on IIS. Problem occurs with .net application on IIS only.

I tried many solutions which I had found here, but none resolved the problem.

What's matter? Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a relevant entry in the event viewer that you could include?

Comment: Hm... No, I didn't see. IIS log has not information too. But I found message in windows log: "HTTP/1.1 DEBUG /website/Default.aspx - 1 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue ASP .NET+v4.0"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the message in event viewer:

> "Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in
>   the .NET Runtime at IP 6B484BC2 (6B300000) with exit code 80131506."

*It was caused by updates of .Net Framework 4.5*. I uninstalled last update. It solved the problem.

**Tip: How to check event viewer.** Visual Studio > View > Server Explorer > SERVER_NAME > Right click on "Event Log" > Launch Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Setup.

There is information about the error: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103/en-us. But hotfix is available by request to Microsoft only.

I don't remember number of "harmful" update. But I think, everybody will be able to find last updates to remove them.

Comment: **Important notice**. Problem had been detected in MS Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I found my issue at `Event Viewer> Windows Logs> Application`.  The code was trying to create a file at `system32\inetsrv ` which was failing

Answer (score 17):

This can be caused in ASP.NET when an infinite loop occurs.

A common example is rendering a partial view which then renders itself in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: This was the case for me.

Comment: Unfortunately me too!

Comment: Lol i m so dumb, i was searching and updating everything and i totally forgot that last piece of code that i had put. Thank you so much for pointing the obvious!

Comment: Although I hadn't been able to find the exact line but it seems that me too have some difficulty with my loop codes as well. As this error will not appear when I jump from my problematic function.

Answer (score 9):

We fixed this isse. 
For us, it was because of the permission levels to write into log. Changed the permissions in IIS.

Repeat this step for each site.

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Select site.
3. Open Authentication
4. Edit "Anonymous Authentication" Credentials. Change to use Application Pool Identity.
5. IIS Reset

Comment: Also found the message from another answer in the event viewer, for now this solution seemed to have fixed this. Message found: .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFAE0BE9346 (00007FFAE0BA0000) with exit code 80131506.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution. Just follow the step below.

 1) Open IIS.

 2) Go to your Application Pool.

 3) Right-click on it -> Advanced Settings...

 4) Under Process Model, change Identify from "ApplicationPoolIndentity" to "LocalSystem"

 5) Restart your IIS.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, mostly the issue is because of the code, that is going in infinite loop, end up with stackoverflow exception.

Just commented all the code in Home Page and tried, page starts working, later un-commented major functionality one after another, figured it out that Controller Rendering is going in infinite loop. Found a fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that a DLL that my app needed to load was no longer in the bin folder.  Looking in `Event Viewer> Windows Logs> Application` is how I found out what the issue was and which missing dll was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my IIS Application Pool for the app was set to .NET 4.5 (Classic). I switched it to non-classic, restarted IIS and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me because my .dll being used by the server was not the same version as the .dll being used by my client application.

In short: Make sure your application and website are using the same dll's

Answer (score 0):

If it is a win32 exception
Open the Advanced settings dialog of the Application pooland
set: Enable 32-Bit Applications to **True**

Answer (score 0):

I was calling  async Task methods from a  Parallel.ForEach. In develop I had not problem, but in production I got this error. I Suppose the resorces of SO were not enought.

I could see the error log in event view log of Windows, here it show the stacktrace.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30247628)